# Solution of the Schroedinger equation with degeneracy & density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, density-operator

As it's written in the title I am trying to solve the Schroedinger equation, when we also consider degeneracy.

$H|\phi_{n,t}\rangle=E_n |\phi_{n,t}\rangle$, where t represents the degeneracy of the eigenstate.

An arbitrary ket $\Psi$ can be expressed as a liner superposition of the basis ket,the eigenstates of the system:

$|\Psi\rangle=\Sigma_{n,t}c_{n,t}|\phi_{n,t}\rangle$.

The Schroendinger equation is:

$i\hbar\frac \partial {\partial t}|\Psi\rangle=H|\Psi\rangle$

$i\hbar\frac \partial {\partial t}\langle \phi_{n,t}|\Psi\rangle=\langle \phi_{n,t}|H|\Psi\rangle$

$i\hbar \frac\partial {\partial t} c_{n,t}(t)=E_nc_{n,t}(t)$.

This is an ODE, where if you express $c_{n,t}=A\cdot e^{\alpha t}$, you should get the result, if I am not mistaken. But the result I get it's not the one I have in my notes, which is:

$c_{n,t}(t)=c_{n,t}(t_0)e^{\frac {-iE_n(t-t_0)} h}$, the full expression, with a possible value in the initial moment.

Can anyone help me find out how we can get this result?

As for the density matrix, the following equation is true:

$\frac {\partial \rho(t)} {\partial t}=\frac i \hbar [H,\rho]$. This result(the right side) you can get when you substitue $\rho=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ , which is how we express the density matrix of a pure state. My question is, can we find the same result if we express the density matrix in the following form: $\rho = \Sigma_ik_i|\phi\rangle_i$, where $|\phi\rangle_i$ can be eigenstates (mix of them) or also arbitrary states, which can be expressed as a linear superposition of some basis ket that the system has.

Comment: $\rho = \ldots |\phi\rangle$ does not make much sense if $\rho$ is a density operator...

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have an operator with a degenerate spectrum, one uses a set of observables that commute with your observable and with each other to 'pin down' a specific eigenbasis. You do this with, for example, the hydrogen atom, where you use $L^2$ and $L_z$ to pin down a specific basis for $H$, $|nlm\rangle$.

Let's say we want to find an energy eigenbasis for some Hamiltonian with a degenerate spectrum $H$. We find mutually commuting observables $A,B,C,...$, and construct a simultaneous, orthonormal, and complete eigenbasis:
$$[H,A]=[H,B]=[H,C]=\cdots=0 \text{ gives us a basis } |E_na'b'c\cdots\rangle$$
Let's use a generalized label to cover all these; thus, we now have a basis $|K'\rangle$ (every value of $K'$ corresponds to a particular ket). Assuming our Hamiltonian is time independent, you can solve this as follows:
\begin{align*}
\partial_t\langle K'|\psi\rangle &=-\frac{iE_{K'}}{\hbar}\langle K'|\psi\rangle\\
\langle K'|\psi(t)\rangle&=\exp\left(-\frac{iE_{K'}t}{\hbar}\right)\langle K'|\psi\rangle\\
\langle x'|\psi\rangle &=\sum_{K'}\langle x'|K'\rangle\langle K'|\psi(t)\rangle \\
&=\sum_{K'}\langle x'|K'\rangle\exp\left(-\frac{iE_{K'}t}{\hbar}\right)\langle K'|\psi(0)\rangle 
\end{align*}
However, $\langle x'|\psi(t)\rangle\equiv\psi(x',t)$ and $\langle x'|K'\rangle\equiv E_{n,a'b'c'\cdots}(x')$. We define $c_n(0)=\langle K'|\psi(0)\rangle$. Then, the above becomes $$\boxed{\psi(x',t)=\sum_{n,a',\cdots}c_n(0)\exp\left(-\frac{iE_{K'}t}{\hbar}\right)E_{n,a',\cdots}(x')}$$

---

Sakurai says,

> A pure ensemble by definition is a collection of physical systems such that every member is characterized by the same ket $|\alpha\rangle$. In contrast, in a mixed ensemble, a fraction of the members with relative population $w_1$ is characterized by $|\alpha^{(1)}\rangle$, some other fraction with relative population $w_2$, [sic] by $|\alpha^{(2)}\rangle$, and so on. Roughly speaking, a mixed ensemble can be viewed as a mixture of pure ensembles.
>
> Sakurai, J.J. & Napolitano, J. *Modern Quantum Mechanics.* 3rd Ed., pg. 171

These $w_i$ add to one, and the $|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle$ can be literally any state. We define the density matrix as $$\rho\equiv \sum_i w_i|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle\langle \alpha^{(i)}|$$
This general expression (for arbitrary kets) obeys the relation given.
\begin{align*}
i\hbar\partial_t\rho&= \sum_i w_i i\hbar\partial_t(|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle\langle \alpha^{(i)}|)\\
&=\sum_i w_i \left(i\hbar\partial_t|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle\langle \alpha^{(i)}|+|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle i\hbar\partial_t\langle \alpha^{(i)}|\right)\\
&=\sum_i w_i \left(H|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle\langle \alpha^{(i)}|-|\alpha^{(i)}\rangle \langle \alpha^{(i)}|H\right)\\
&= [H,\rho]
\end{align*}

Comment: Commutativity is not a transitive relation... Also, your last relations only hold if all the $\alpha$ obey the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: @Jakob oh, I forgot to write "and with each other;" thanks for pointing that out! I'll edit that straightaway. As for your second point, I am working in the Schrodinger picture.

Comment: @Jakob There's a subtle distinction to be made here. To borrow an example from the question you linked: the definition of position eigenstates doesn't change with time, but if you actually prepare a particle in a position eigenstate (that's impossible, but let's gloss over that), it will most certainly evolve in time, as Pisanty points out. The definition hasn't changed, but the prepared particle's state changed in accordance with the SE. Eigenstates of the Hamiltonian evolve with time (the phase changes).

Comment: $|E_n(t)\rangle=\exp(iHt/\hbar)|E_n(0)\rangle=\exp(iE_n t/\hbar)|E_n(0)\rangle$. The predictions themselves don't change, of course, but the state vector itself certainly does.